# Need hyperlink for endnote numbers (endnotes numbers are page numbers)

Tags: endnotes, hyperlink

I need to display the corresponding pagenumbers of the `endnotes` instead of actual `endnote` numbers, for this, I've modified the codes as below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}
\usepackage{endnotes}%
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\enoteformat{%
\leftskip\z@\RaggedRight\parindent=\z@\parskip\z@\def\@textsuperscript{}%
  \@hangfrom{\leavevmode{\hbox to 20\p@{\makeenmark\hss}\ignorespaces}}}%
\def\enoteheading{\chapter*{Notes}%
}%
\def\enotesize{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont}%
\let\theendnote=\thepage
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on first page}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on third page}

\clearpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

In this, I need `hyperlink` for the `endnote` numbers (respective page numbers), please suggest...

Comment: Do you want to link to or from the endnote?

Comment: Yes, if I click the `endnote` (i.e., `page number`) number, it should go to the corresponding page, hope I'm clear, please let me know if further clarification needs...(sorry for my language, if my explanation is not clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperref already has anchors for pages of the form `page.1` etc.  The tricky bit is that `\theendnote` gives the current page, not the original one.

You can ignore the `\label` and `\ref`.  I was just experimenting.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}
\usepackage{endnotes}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\enoteformat{%
\leftskip\z@\RaggedRight\parindent=\z@\parskip\z@\def\@textsuperscript{}%
  \@hangfrom{\leavevmode{\hbox to 20\p@{\hyperlink{page.\@theenmark}{\makeenmark}\hss}\ignorespaces}}}%
\def\enoteheading{\chapter*{Notes}%
}%
\def\enotesize{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont}%
\let\theendnote=\thepage
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on first page\label{test}}

\ref{test}

\ref{second}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on third page\label{second}}

\clearpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's works like a champ....Thanks lot and lot...