# wrong page number display (combination of hyperref, endnotes)

Tags: page-numbering

My codes (thanks to `John Kormylo` [Need hyperlink for endnote numbers (endnotes numbers are page numbers)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617377/need-hyperlink-for-endnote-numbers-endnotes-numbers-are-page-numbers/617421#617421) for his supports to achieve to print `pagenumber` instead of `endnote` numbers) are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}
\usepackage{endnotes}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\enoteformat{%
\def\makeenmark{\@makeenmark}%
\leftskip\z@\RaggedRight\parindent=\z@\parskip\z@\def\@textsuperscript{}%
  \@hangfrom{\leavevmode{\hbox to 20\p@{\hyperlink{page.\@theenmark}{\makeenmark}\hss}\ignorespaces}}}%
\def\enoteheading{\chapter*{Notes}%
}%
\def\enotesize{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont}%
\let\theendnote=\thepage
\def\makeenmark{\relax}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[1-2]

This is just for check, indication of first endnote\endnote{End note on first page\label{test}} This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check 
This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check
This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check
This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check
This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check
This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check
This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check
This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check
This is just for check indication of second endnote\endnote{End note on second page\label{test}} This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check This is just for check 

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on third page\label{second}}

\clearpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

First endnotes lies on first page and the page number displayed correctly, and the second endnote lies on second page, but it display first page only, but it should display as `2`, please refer the screenshot:

[image]

This problem have occurred if a text para continues from page to page....

Please advise how to get the exact page numbers...

Now I understood that giving `\thepage` is not the better way, can any one please suggest in what other alternative method to achieve my task, i.e., printing respective `page numbers` for the `endnote` instead of the actual `endnote` counter, please....

Comment: You can't do `\let\theendnote=\thepage`, this is not reliable due to the asynchronous page breaking.

Answer (score 0):

If You remove `%\let\theendnote=\thepage` You will get the result you want:
[image]

Comment: If I do that, then I couldn't meet my requirement to display the respective `page numbers` of the `endnote`, anyhow, thanks...